# <video> html tag isn't working while using Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, video, media-player

This is my first time using Codeigniter PHP framework. In my root folder, I have a folder called output that holds a test.mp4 file. In one of my view php pages, I have the following code

```
<video controls loop>
    <source src="C:/xampp/htdocs/project/output/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

The video window is displayed, but the video does not play. I have used the  tag in other projects not using this framework and have had it working fine before (which leads me to believe it is me using Codeigniter incorrectly)

Chrome: shows window; does not play
Edge: does not play; displays "Aborted" on the video window

Comment: Place all videos outside application folder. and call it back.

Comment: <source src="C:/xampp/htdocs/project/application/output/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: you have to put video folder not In root folder , put it inside application  folder.

Comment: I changed my src to what you recommended. I received the same problem.

Comment: Use video URL instead its path on disk, something like <source src="http ://localhost/project/application/output/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: thanks for the additional suggestion. I plugged <source src="http://localhost/project/output/test.mp4" type="video/mpeg"> with no luck. Confirmed the file was in the correct location. Not much documentation on embedded videos with codeigniter either. still digging

Comment: so manually adding http://localhost/project/output/test.mp4 gives me a 404 error from Codeigniter; I tried the same tactic with a different project and the mp4 pulled up. I am convinced there has to be a setting within codeigniter blocking this ability.

Comment: I followed this tutorial to setup codeigniter if this provides any information to anyone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I752ofYu7ag

Comment: Try this <source src="http://localhost/project/output/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: can you autoload $autoload['helper'] = array('html', 'url', 'file', 'form');